# DirectoryServicesComException on production but not local machine C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, active-directory

The code works great on my local machine but when published to the server it throws the DirectoryServiceCOMException on the

```
results = mySearcher.FindAll();
```

line of the code. 
My function passes the contents of two searchboxes where the user can lookup an employee by name or position:

```
        // Bind to the users container.
        string path = "LDAP://DC=DOMAIN,DC=TLD";
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path);

        // Create a DirectorySearcher object.
        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        // Set a filter for users with the name test.
        mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)";

        if (employeeName != "")
        {
            mySearcher.Filter = mySearcher.Filter + "(name=*" + employeeName + "*)";
        }
        if (position != "")
        {
            mySearcher.Filter = mySearcher.Filter + "(title=*" + position + "*)";
        }
        mySearcher.Filter = mySearcher.Filter + ")";
        mySearcher.Sort = new SortOption("sn", System.DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending);


        // Use the FindAll method to return objects to a 
        // SearchResultCollection.
        results = mySearcher.FindAll();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible reasons:

1. the app pool identity on the server is not authorized to connect to the AD. check the app pool identity, set it to the domain admin account for validation
2. the server is not connected to AD

Comment: Changing the application pool identity to network service fixed the problem.  Thanks